# Is it possible to access child class variable through parent class reference?

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child

Can someone pls let me know the output of this code?

```
public Class A {

    public int count = 5;    

    public void test() {
        // some code
    }    
}

public Class B extends A {

    public int count = 10;

    public void test() {
        //some code
    }
}

public Class Check {

    A a = new A();
    A b = new B();

    public void myTestMethod() {
        a.count; //should call A?
        a.test; //should call A?
        b.count; //which count is called here? compiler error?
        b.test; //should call B?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  There's this special tool that can give you the output of any Java program.  It's called Java.  Try it out for yourself!

Comment: `Can someone pls let me know the output of this code?` Would it cost you an arm to try and execute it yourself? Besides, I think it's incomplete.

Comment: Use this if you don't have an IDE available: http://ideone.com/.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @keppil - I didn't have an IDE and wasn't aware about ideone. Thanks for not giving an angry rebuke like some other scholars :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    a.count;    => yes you can
    a.test;     => yes you can
    b.count;    => count = 5; its didn't shows the compiler error its return the 5.
    b.test;  => Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Java inheritance lets the extending test over-ride or hide methods from the class it extends. So if B extends A and both have the same method then when you call `b.method()` it will call that method in B.

Inside B you can choose which method is called by doing either `method()` or `super.method()` to specify whether to call the super implementation or not.